# Reinitialize all member variables in derived class only

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I have two classes:

```
class NonCopyable {
private:
    int key;
protected:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable &) = delete;
};

class Derived : public NonCopyable {
private:
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    float f;
    int* ptr;
public:
    Derived() : f(5.0f), ptr(nullptr) {}
    ~Derived();
};
```

Now, I'd like to reinitialize all the values in the *Derived* class and call the appropriate destructors. That is, the *NonCopyable* class should not be touched, but the *Derived* class should be changed as if it was newly initialized.

What is the simplest way of achieving this goal? I am trying to avoid making a member function which manually reinitializes every member variable.

---

Clearly, I can not use the following approach:

```
Derived d;
// [...] many changes to d
d = Derived();
```

because the copy constructor is deleted from the *NonCopyable* class and the fact that it would change the member variables of *NonCopyable* had this not been the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It becomes much easier if you move your private data to a separate aggregate:

```
struct DerivedData {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    float f = 5.0;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
};

class Derived : public NonCopyable {
    DerivedData data;
public:
    ~Derived();
    void reset() { data = DerivedData(); }
};
```